# Displaying page response time and AJAX request response times with Rack middleware

Tags: rack, middleware

I want to write a piece of Rack middleware that will display the response time for rendering the page, as well as the response times for any AJAX requests made on the page. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something based on [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware). It injects response times as HTML comments into your page source. For AJAX requests, you can inspect the content-type/x-requested-with headers to inject the timing information in the appropriate format.

Comment: If I detect an AJAX request, how do I inject the response time to the original HTML document?

Comment: That you can't do that (the original HTTP request has been terminated by the time you perform the AJAX request). What you can do, however, is to have a generic AJAX response handler on your page that extracts this information from the AJAX response before handing it on to your application.

Comment: That makes sense. How would you implement that generic AJAX response handler though?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Looks like you can hook into $(document).ajaxComplete if you're using jQuery. The MVC mini profiler does this (and also has some javascript that handles ASP.NET AJAX calls as well): http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/UI/Includes.js